# Relative node position on path

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the MWE using tikz and positioning:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) {A};
    \node (B) [right=1cm of A] {B};
    \draw [->] (A) -- (B);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would like to eliminate the standalone definition of node B, while still producing the same output.

Something like this (illegal) attempt:

```
\node (A) {A};
\draw [->] (A) -- node [right=1cm of A] {B};
```

Sure, not a big deal, but I keep coming back to trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of options.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article} % never use minimal

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) {A};
    \node (B) [right=1cm of A] {B};
    \draw [->] (A) -- (B);
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) {A};
    \draw [->] (A.east) -- ++(1cm,0) node[right] {B};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) {A};
    \draw [->] node[right=1cm of A] (B) {B}
           (A) -- (B);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding `minimal`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tikz-cd`, if you prefer. With `[10em]` you can adjust the lenght of the arrow.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow[r] &[10em] B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```